# Need to Understand the CDC flow of Debezium Postgres Source Connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Folks,

I am trying to understand the CDC process of Debezium Postgres source connector as i suspect data loss. Here is my scenario, I have a connector name `"deb-connector"` that pulls data from about 10 tables via the replication slot `"deb-1"` and plugin `"wal2json"`, everything works fine and all good. Now i wanted to add 2 more tables to the sync up, so i created a new connector named `"deb-connector-updt"` with additional 2 tables hop on to the same rep slot `"deb-1"`. It took some time initially (as it normally does) for the snapshot to finish and running. Here is my question,

1. As far as the snapshot process is concerned, my understanding is that its gonna take a new snapshot for the second connector (pls correct me if i am wrong).?
2. If it does, the initial process would be READ events for all records in the db and all records (2.5K recs) should have flown to kafka no matter what, right? But i don't see them, instead i see only the cdc records (23 recs) flowing.

This can only happen if it doesn't take new snapshot and basically start from where it left off (that makes sense only if the snapshot is tied to the slot). (or) Should i create a new slot whenever i want to add/remove tables list from the config (that doesn't make sense at all)?

I would highly appreciate if the experts can answer this! Thank you!

Comment: As I know debezium is work like this: First It, it fetches the historical data (Like Select * from tables) and stores the offset. after this completes, it captures CDC events. Are you using kafka-connect standalone mode or distributed mode?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We are using in distributed mode. Yes, snapshot is fetching the historical data only, but does it get created every time for as many as connectors?

Comment: Figured out myself, the snapshot is directly tied to replication slot (physical as well as logical). All the connectors that use the slot `deb-1` will always refer the snapshot tied to that slot, i.e. only cdc will be captured always! For new snapshot, have to create a new slot!  [Postgres Logical Replication Slot](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding-explanation.html)